# How do I get the keys inside a C# model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to have a loop where I can get every object key in my model.

I have this model:

```
public class RoleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel TrackAndTrace { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel MailProcessing { get; set; }
}
```

I want to achieve something like:

```
for (var i = 0, len = Object.keys(RoleModel).length; i < len; i++) {

  Console.Writeline(Object.keys(RoleModel)[i])

}
```

which would return

```
ID
RoleName
TrackAndTrace 
MailProcessing
```

Comment: If you need to do this in c#, there are are possibility that you doing something wrong or decision made based on the wrong assumptions. Can you explain why you need to do this?

Comment: @Fabio it's quite hard to explain but I have multiple checkboxes for user role access  with 'view', 'download',  'modify' as column and module name as rows. I pass all the value via array and each of the row is saved 1 row in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you need a Reflection. Reflection is Virtual Machine API. You can use it for get metadata of class. Please see example:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RoleModel).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.Writeline(property.Name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(RoleModel).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Console.Writeline(property.Name);
}
```